# Typescript Cloud function not compiling

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-functions

I have following cloud function to get data from the firebase datastore but it doesn't compile and am not sure how to fix this.

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const db = admin.firestore();
const usersObj = db.collection('users')

export const getUsers = async () => {
    let allUsers: Array<any> = [];
    await usersObj.get().then(users => {
        users.forEach(user => {
            allUsers[user.id] = user.data();
        });
    });
    return allUsers;
}
```

> error: error TS7015: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because
>   index expression is not of type 'number'. allOrders[order.id] =
>   order.data();

Comment: Is `user.id` a number?

Comment: @Héctor its a string... GUID

Comment: I think that's the problem. Array index should be a number. You could change allUsers to be an object, or use forEach index as array index instead of user's GUID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't index an array using a string. To solve it, you can:

Use `forEach` index as array index:

```
users.forEach((user, i) => {
    allUsers[i] = user.data();
});
```

or push items to the `allUsers` array:

```
users.forEach(user => {
    allUsers.push(user.data());
});
```

Comment: great. thanks... I was using push before but removed it during fixing other type issues with allUsers...

Comment: great, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

If you want to transform your array elements into a new array, you could also use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
allUsers = users.map(user => user.data());
```

Comment: actually what I wanted to do was something like `users.forEach(user => {
    allUsers.push({ id: user.id, ...user.data() });
});` I don't know how to do it using .map

Comment: Something like this: `allUsers = users.map(user => Object.assign({ id: user.id }, user.data()));`

Comment: doesn't seems to work. getting error `Property 'map' does not exist on type 'QuerySnapshot'.`